# How to parse a date in TypeScript with d3? parse does not exist on type?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, underscore.js, dc.js

Hello I have a problem with parsing the isoFormat.
I would like to parse it and get it in a piechart of dc.js.

Property parse does not exist on type(date:Date)=>string..but why?

The application is written in angular 4 TypeScript.

Maybe there is a problem with underscore:

```
console.log(dataSet);
   // var fullDateFormat = d3.timeFormat('%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z');
    var fullDateFormat = d3.isoFormat;
    var yearFormat = d3.timeFormat('%Y');
    var monthFormat = d3.timeFormat('%b');
    var dayOfWeekFormat = d3.timeFormat('%a');

    _.each(dataSet, function (d: any) {
     // d.count = +d.count;

     // d.first_had_dt = fullDateFormat.parse(d.scanDate);//Here is the Problem; 

      d.first_had_year = +yearFormat(d.first_had_dt);
```

I cant get the solution. :/

Comment: Parse is not a part of `d3.timeFormat` as far as I know. It has `isoParse`, `timeParse`, and `utcParse`. Have you tried using one of those? If you want to use `parse`, you need to convert the time to a specific locale.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is a problem with d3v3 versus d3v4.

At present [dc.js is only compatible with version 3 of d3.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173) and it looks like you are using the version 4 syntax.

You could [consult the version 3 reference for `d3.time`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md#d3time-time) - the functionality did not change all that much in this area, just the function/class names.